# Question about Suzuki's Theory of Exceptional Characters

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, sylow-theory, characters

As elegant as Suzuki's theory is, the set up requires that the number of conjugacy classes of $p$-elements in a cyclic T.I. (as an example) Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$, $e$,  is at least 2, in order to produce at least two exceptional characters of $N_G(P)$ of equal degrees which in turn generates a virtual character which vanishes off $p$-elements.

My question is, what happens when $e = 1$? Is there a analogous theory to treat this case since the end result is that $Irr(G)$ is still largely controlled by $N_G(P)$? (For instance McKay's conjecture still holds)

To illustrate, the theory of exceptional characters would work perfectly for $G = A_5$ for $p = 5$ since $N_G(P) \cong D_{10}$ have two exceptional characters of degree 2. However when $G = S_5$, it seems that the theory won't work since in this case $N_G(P) \cong C_5 \rtimes C_4$ has only 1 non-linear character, of degree 4. But $Irr(G)$ and $Irr(N_G(P))$ are strongly connected in this case.  Is there a similar theory that addresses cases like $G = S_5$ with $p = 5$? I'd be grateful to know any literature on such theory if it exists.

And I suppose when $e=1$ it's not always possible to find a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ for which the theory of exceptional characters would work, as in the $A_5 \unlhd S_5$ case?

Comment: Now cross-posted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410532)